# How To Check Checkbox Is Already Checked Or Not

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

As per scenario if  checkbox is already checked then i need to print only text and if check box is not checked then i need to click on checkbox.

```
//-Check sandbox test client checkbox is already checked or not if not then tick on checkbox
boolean sandboxClientCheckbox = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='eplChkBoxWrapper']//label[@id='acChkSandboxClientForLbl']")).isSelected();       
System.out.println("Check checkbox value " +sandboxClientCheckbox);
if(sandboxClientCheckbox == true)   {
    Utils.pauseTestExecution(3);
    System.out.println("Checkbox is already checked  ");            
} else {
            driver.findElement(By.id("acChkSandboxClientForLbl")).click();
}
```

When i am printing value of checkbox then this is showing false. But first time this is always checked

HTML values for checkbox is :

```
<div class="eplChkBoxWrapper">==$0
 <input type="checkbox" id="acChkSandboxClient" class="eplChkBox" checked>
<label id="acChkSandboxClientForLbl" for="acChkSandboxClient">
::after
</label>
```

Can anyone help me how i can check this checkbox is already checked or not at the time of execution . I have shared DOM elementes `enter code here`

Comment: You have mentioned `first time this is always checked` can there still be an _usecase_ when **check box is not checked**? If so update the question with the HTML of the element being in _checked_ and _unchecked_ state.

Comment: @DebanjanB  Yes when we click on create then in form this is already checked .  but in some cases it will not checked .  because of this i need to write this condition  if already checked then print only  text   and if this is not checked then click on checkbox.

Comment: @DebanjanB   HTML tag is same only different is   . If checkbox is not checked  then      label tag changed   like     <label id="acChkSandboxClientForLbl" for="acChkSandboxClient"></label>    Only this is a difference in HTML tag

Comment: @DebanjanB i have posted one more question  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50213059/how-to-check-checkbox-is-already-checked-or-not-on-edit-page  can you please check and reply if you can help me on this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check Checkbox is already checked or not on edit page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50213059/how-to-check-checkbox-is-already-checked-or-not-on-edit-page)

Answer (score 0):

```
if($("#check").prop('checked') == true){
do something
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain this because i used same code but again this is going in else section .  But checkbox is already checked it should print .   In input tag we have  checked   this is same in both condition weather checkbox is checked or not .

Comment: Checkbox cb = cg.getSelectedCheckbox();
if(null != cb) {
  //not checked
} else {
  System.out.println(cb.getLabel() + " is checked");
}

Comment: getSelectedCheckbox(); option not showing with     Checkbox sandboxClientCheckbox = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='eplChkBoxWrapper']//label[@id='acChkSandboxClientForLbl']")).get

Answer (score 0):

To validate if the desired checkbox is already checked and print only text or else if check box is not checked then to click on checkbox you can use the following code block :

```
if(driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='eplChkBoxWrapper']/input[@checked]")).size() != 0)
{
    System.out.println("Checkbox is already checked");
    // do any other work
}
else
{
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='eplChkBoxWrapper']/label[@for='acChkSandboxClient']")).click();
    // do any other work
}
```

Comment: Thanks this is working fine in one page .  I have two pages one is create and one id edit   .  In edit page i am again verifying checkbox is checked or not . but same code is not working on edit page because in input tag checked text not showing in DOM .  can you please help me in this scenario also     .  I am sharing DOM element from Edit User page       <div class="eplChkBoxWrapper">==$0
 <input type="checkbox" id="acChkSandboxClient" class="eplChkBox" >
<label id="acChkSandboxClientForLbl" for="acChkSandboxClient">
::after
</label>

Comment: @TarunDabbs That seems to be a separate question all together. Can you raise a new question with your new requirement please?

Comment: I have already accepted this answer  .i know this is a different question . but only minor difference . Please can you suggest in comment .

Comment: Sorry i didn't check negative condition  currently i have executed and if checkbox is not checked then above code should be go in else section . but if checkbox is not checked in this condition this is also going in if condition and this is not working properly .

Comment: @TarunDabbs Check out my updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: I executed above updated code but everytime this is going in if condition .  If checkbox is checked then this is going inside if condition   and  if checkbox is not checked again this is going in if condition

Comment: @TarunDabbs Check out my updated answer and let me know the status.

Answer (score 0):

one methods present in webelement interface we can check by using it. method name is isSelected().its return type is boolean.if it is true than it is selected.if it is false than we can check by click().

Comment: Thanks Ajit checkbox is already checked and this is returning false . It should be return true

Answer (score 0):

Find element:

```
WebElement chk = driver.findElement(By.id("chkElement1"))
```

so this code covers all possibilities, and check if already are checked.

```
public void checkItem(boolean flgON) {
        boolean flgState = Boolean.valueOf(chk.getAttribute("checked"));

// if state is checked and want to un-check (flg == false)//
        if (flgState && (!flgON)) {
            switchSystemNotifications.click();
        }
// if state is notchecked and want check (flg == true)//
        if (!flgState && (flgON)) {
            switchSystemNotifications.click();
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply  .   Can you please reply if DOM element is changed like    <div class="eplChkBoxWrapper">==$0
 <input type="checkbox" id="acChkSandboxClient" class="eplChkBox" >
<label id="acChkSandboxClientForLbl" for="acChkSandboxClient">
::after
</label>    .   If checked not showing in input tag then  getAttribute will not work . Can you please help me on this

Comment: String selectedCB = "";
String jsScript = "var selchbox = [];"
    +"var inpfields = document.getElementsByName('city[]');"
    +"var nr_inpfields = inpfields.length;"
    +"for(var i=0; i<nr_inpfields; i++) {"
    +"    if(inpfields[i].type == 'checkbox' && inpfields[i].checked == true) selchbox.push(inpfields[i].value);"
    +"  }"
    +"var selected;"
    +"selected = selchbox.join('#') + \"#\";"
    +"return selected;";
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
selectedCB = (String) executor.executeScript(jsScript);
String[] selectedB = selectedCB.split("#");

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue a long time ago, and I used this code, just to "patch" current issue that I had, try it out, it is not elegant solution, but in pinch check it out:

```
String selectedCB = "";
String jsScript = "var selchbox = [];"
    +"var inpfields = document.getElementsByName('city[]');"
    +"var nr_inpfields = inpfields.length;"
    +"for(var i=0; i<nr_inpfields; i++) {"
    +"    if(inpfields[i].type == 'checkbox' && inpfields[i].checked == true) selchbox.push(inpfields[i].value);"
    +"  }"
    +"var selected;"
    +"selected = selchbox.join('#') + \"#\";"
    +"return selected;";
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
selectedCB = (String) executor.executeScript(jsScript);
String[] selectedB = selectedCB.split("#");
```

Comment: Sorry but i really don't know how to use this code in my project .checked  text in input tag  is fixed in both condition  weather checkbox is checked or not .

Comment: Sorry this is code for multiple checkboxes, it returns multiple booleans, but with little tweak, it might use You. Sorry if this wasn't helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `element.isEnabled()`? if so try to get the attribute checked using `getAttribute` function. I think it gonna disappear when the checkbox is unchecked.

Comment: Thanks for providing a suggestion. But answers on stackoverflow should be fully fledged answers. They shouldn't contain questions or guesses. That is what the comments are for