# How to check Checkbox is already checked or not on edit page

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

As per scenario if checkbox is already checked ,then I need to print only text and if check box is not checked, then I need to click on checkbox.

```
    //-Check sandbox test client checkbox is already checked or not if not then tick on checkbox
    boolean sandboxClientCheckbox = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='eplChkBoxWrapper']//label[@id='acChkSandboxClientForLbl']")).isSelected();       
    System.out.println("Check checkbox value " +sandboxClientCheckbox);
    if(sandboxClientCheckbox == true)   {
        Utils.pauseTestExecution(3);
        System.out.println("Checkbox is already checked  ");            
    } else {
                driver.findElement(By.id("acChkSandboxClientForLbl")).click();
    }
```

HTML Tag is

```
<div class="eplChkBoxWrapper">==$0
 <input type="checkbox" id="acChkSandboxClient" class="eplChkBox">
<label id="acChkSandboxClientForLbl" for="acChkSandboxClient">
::after
</label>
```

Can anyone help me? how I can check this checkbox is already checked or not at the time of execution ? I have shared DOM elements.

Comment: Update the question with the HTML of the element being in _unchecked_ and _checked_ state.

Comment: With checked   <div class="eplChkBoxWrapper">==$0
 <input type="checkbox" id="acChkSandboxClient" class="eplChkBox">
<label id="acChkSandboxClientForLbl" for="acChkSandboxClient">
::after
</label>              And without check   <div class="eplChkBoxWrapper">==$0
 <input type="checkbox" id="acChkSandboxClient" class="eplChkBox">
<label id="acChkSandboxClientForLbl" for="acChkSandboxClient"></label>

Comment: @DebanjanB Any update on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`isSelected()` doesn't work on `LABEL` tags, only `INPUT`s. The `INPUT` is in the HTML you posted.

```
boolean sandboxClientCheckbox = driver.findElement(By.id("acChkSandboxClient")).isSelected();
```

Comment: Hi JeffC  isChecked() not showing in suggestion list.   and  driver.findElement(By.id("acChkSandboxClientForLbl")).isSelected()  this is returning  false in both condition  when checkbox is checked and when checkbox is not checked

Comment: Sorry... posted the wrong ID in the code. Try now.

Comment: Hi JeffC  Thank you so much now this is working fine

Comment: Hi JeffC i accepted your answer because this works for me.for vote i don't have points when i am trying to give you vote then i am getting message,

Comment: That's fine... glad it helped.